# Primefaces open p:fileUpload programmatically

Tags: javascript, jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I'm using tinyMCE, and i'm implementing a custom file manager. 
I would like to trigger the `Choose` button of the `p:fileUpload` (it is hidden) when the user clicks on the `Browse` button in the tinyMCE window.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:fileUpload id="fileUpload" widgetVar="fileUpload"/>
</h:form>
```

And here is the Javascript code i'm trying: 
`PF('fileUpload').chooseButton.click()`
But it wouldn't trigger the `Choose` button.
I tried on both Chrome and Firefox.
How can I trigger the Choose button programmatically from javascript?

Answer (score 3):

Just faced this problem, this solution has worked for me:

```
onclick="$('input[type=file]').click();"
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution:

```
PF('fileUpload').input.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice from PF docs:

```
<p:fileUpload id="pf-file-upload" widgetVar="pf-file-upload" mode="advanced".../>

<p:button value="Upload" icon="pi pi-pencil"
onclick="return PF('pf-file-upload').show();"/>
```